# Bulk rename functions in IDA Pro

Tags: ida

I have a list of tenthousands of {Address} - {Function Name} pairs I dumped with a tool I wrote.
Now I want to rename all functions so for example sub_123456 becomes "FooBar", because the list says so.

Any way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such cases i would load the list in [Vim](http://www.vim.org), change the list to have two columns, the first the addresses, the second the desired names. Like this:

```
123456 FooBar
124584 BarFoo
```

Then do `:%s/^\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\+\)/MakeName(0x\1, "\2");`, ending up with a list like this:

```
MakeName(0x123456, "FooBar");
MakeName(0x124584, "BarFoo");
```

Then copy the entire Vim buffer to the clipboard with `1G` and `"*yG`.
Then in IDA type `Shift-F2` to open the manual script editor, and paste using Cmd-V or Ctrl-V.

Comment: And if you use Visual Studio instead of Vim do a replace with Regular Expression `{:h} {:i}` and a replace with `MakeName(0x\1, "\2");`